# My hadoop reducer writes the output to the context only if I write the original value to the context

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have this code:

```java
@Override
protected void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    Set<String> mySet = new HashSet<>();
    Map<String, String myMap = new HashMap<>();
    for (Text value : values) {
        // context.write(key, value);
        ... 
    }
    for (String str : mySet) {
        if(myMap.containsKey(str)){
            outputValue.set(str + myMap.get(str));
            context.write(key, outputValue);
        }
    }
}
```

If I uncomment the commented line, the output is written as well as each input value. However, when I comment the line, the output is not written. What could be the issue?

I only want the output to be written to context.

Answer (score 0):

Unclear what you expected since, with the code shown, the set and map are both empty and your conditional is false

Reducers are stateless and do not share data between all instances

Iterate over values, not try to use a new, empty set or map. Or add data to either, rather than write the context, then iterate them (for example, to output unique values)

Comment: I populate the set and map inside the values loop and the conditional turns true. The output is written correctly if I don't comment out the write inside the values loop, without any other change

Comment: In the code provided, no, you don't.  Please edit your question to include your exact code without "...". Plus, unclear why you need both a map and a set. A map cannot have duplicate keys, so there's no reason to use a set to test for this